# Remove directory in url with <a>

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have an english and french version of my website:

```
*website.com/fr/index.php    
*website.com/index.php
```

I have a link to switch from one version to the other, I use a direct link to either :

```
-website.com/fr/index.php
```

or

```
-website.com/index.php.
```

But i would like that the link just adds or removes the /fr after website.com.
So that no matter the page I am on, i will be able to simply switch language version without retourning to index page everytime ...

Thanks in advance for any help =)

Comment: use javascript just have a check and remove it using regex or some function.What you have tried so far can we see?

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava I was just wondering how to go about this =) Having done anything so far

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this

```
var domain = "yourDomain.com";
function changeToFR(){
    location.href = location.href.replace(domain, domain+"/fr");
}

function changeToEN(){
    location.href = location.href.replace(domain + "/fr", domain);
}
```

what this functions will do is to add/remove `fr` from the current URL.

Or as HTML:

```
<a onClick="location.href = location.href.replace('yourDomain.com', 'yourDomain.com/fr');">French</a>
<a onClick="location.href = location.href.replace('yourDomain.com/fr', 'yourDomain.com');">English</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the index.html by using a backslash which means the same, the root directory.

```
<a href="index.html">Homepage</a>
```

would be same as - `<a href="/">Homepage</a>`

You want to link it to another directory, then you would be probably doing this -

```
<a href="en/index.html">English</a>
```

Instead you can have this - `<a href="en">English language</a>`

Make sure that you have index.html in your English language folder, and not index-en.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` with

```
<a href="fr<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">click me </a> <!-- $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; -->
<a href="fr<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">click me </a> <!-- $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; -->
```

Note : It will not work in localhost.if you need it in localhost than you need to make to website alias like www.abc.com not just localhost/abc.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Javascript function to get the current URL

you can use `window.location.href` or `document.URL;`

Then use the javascript split function to split by / `tr.split("/");`

Add the `fr` in the required index.

Then create a single string putting the / back.

then use this jquery code

```
var trigger = $("<a>")
              .attr("href", url)
              .appendTo("body");

            trigger[0].click();
            trigger.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

One function for both versions.

```js
function switchLang(){
 var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
 if(currentPath.substr(0,3) === '/fr'){
  //FR -> EN
  var newPath =  currentPath.substr(3);
  window.location.pathname = newPath; 
 }
 else{
  //EN -> FR
  var newPath = '/fr' + currentPath;
  window.location.pathname = newPath; 
 }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="switchLang();return false;">Switch language</a>
```

Tested for both root folders and subfolders.